# How do I get my noscript tag working on the home page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, noscript

I'm placing a noscript tag in my homepage, just below other script tags, but I don't see anything with javascript disabled. What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to show up on my home page?

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Comment: Hard to say based on the provided information, maybe [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) or the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) helps? Probably moving the tag to `body` would solve your issue.

Comment: Need browser, and a snippet of the view-source that will reproduce the problem.